# Add class active to the current category Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, category, frontend

How I can add a class "active" to the current / selected category? Magento 2.3

```
<?php
 // get the list of all categories
//echo "Hello";
//echo '<div class="hello"></div>';
$_categories = $block->getCategoryCollection();
```

//var_dump($categories);
//echo "end";

```
 $category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
 $categoryId=$category->getId();

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
 $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
 $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

 ?>

 <ul class="category-main">
 <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
    <li class="category">
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>">
            <?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php if ($category->getId() && $category->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
            <?php $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_category->getId());
            ?>
            <?php $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
                <ul class="subcategory-main">
                    <?php foreach($subCats as $subcat): ?>
                        <li class="subcategory">
                                <a class="" href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                                </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How I can add a class "active" to the current / selected category?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code :

```
$category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$categoryId=$category->getId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
$subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

?>

 <ul class="category-main">
 <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
    <li class="category">
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>">
            <?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php if ($category->getId() && $category->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
            <?php $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_category->getId());
            ?>
            <?php $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
                <ul class="subcategory-main">
                    <?php foreach($subCats as $subcat): ?>
                        <?php $class = ($categoryId == $subcat->getId())?'active':''; ?>
                        <li class="subcategory">
                                <a class="<?php echo $class; ?>" href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                                </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I added this below line in foreach :

```
<?php $class = ($categoryId == $subcat->getId())?'active':''; ?>
```

Make sure **$categoryId** is your current category id.

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: yes $categoryId is my current category id but which area put this code @Rohan Hapani

Comment: i try but is not working @Rohan Hapani

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

> app/code/vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/templates/categories.php

```
<?php
// get the list of all categories
//echo "Hello";
//echo '<div class="hello"></div>';
$_categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(); 
//var_dump($categories);
//echo "end";

$category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$categoryId=$category->getId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')- 
>load($categoryId);
$subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
```

?>

```
<ul class="category-main">
<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
    <?php $class = ($categoryId == $_category->getId())?'active':''; ?>
    <li class="category">
        <a class="<?php echo $class; ?>" href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>">
            <?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php if ($category->getId() && $category->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
            <?php $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_category->getId());
            ?>
            <?php $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
                <ul class="subcategory-main">
                    <?php foreach($subCats as $subcat): ?>
                        <li class="subcategory">
                                <a class="" href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                                </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> Css

```
li.category a.active
{
   color: white !important;
}
```